# Show image when btn clicked - live update

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Overview: Using a repeater to display a list of records on screen with a name, a check box, a text area & a submit button.

When text is added to the text area and the adjacent submit button is clicked the record will update in the DB in real time, without a page load. This is done using JQuery which all works fine.

How would i get the image to display on a certain position. i.e inside the text area

thanks for any replies

Comment: Couple of suggestions... If there is only one textarea in the same place; add the loading image to html and position absolutely over the text area and hide it. Then on click show image and on ajax complete hide image. If there are multiples or other variances, you can get <textarea> offset().top & offset().left, append image to body and position on submit click.

Comment: There is one text area per record, and each list could have any number of records, so I will have to hard code for each one, isnt there a way of saying display image ontop of text area where id's are the same? thanks for the reply

Comment: Not really; but you can say get the position for ID, and position Image over it.

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty mockup of the suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/WbU6v/